# ID extraction in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column named `content`in my df(along with many other columns) which has values like this:

```
data = {
    24686: [
        {
            'id': 'new-required-request-property',
            'text': "added the new required request property 'todaySubsectionList'",
            'level': 0,
            'operation': 'PUT',
            'path': '/frequent'
        }
    ],
    85961: '',
    80955: "Backward compatibility errors (1):\nerror at original_source=/Users/, in API GET /api/v2/templates api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation].",
    26854: [
        {
            'id': 'request-parameter-removed',
            'text': "deleted the 'header' request parameter 'Accept'",
            'level': 1,
            'operation': 'GET',
            'path': '/reviews'
        },
        {
            'id': 'request-parameter-removed',
            'text': "deleted the 'header' request parameter 'Content-Type'",
            'level': 1,
            'operation': 'GET',
            'path': '/reviews'
        }
    ],
    30896: [],
    54673: [],
    31920: [],
    6421: ''
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['index', 'content'])
```

I need to extract the `id` and its count ( the number of times it has appeared) and append it back to the original df. My expected output is something like this:

```
content                                                                 count

new-required-request-property,request-parameter-removed        1,2
```

I am not sure how I can do this, any suggestions or ideas will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
# if needed
# from ast import literal_eval
# df["data"] = df["data"].apply(literal_eval)

from collections import Counter

counts = pd.DataFrame([
    (",".join(set(d["id"] for d in lst)),
     ",".join(str(c) for c in Counter(d["id"] for d in lst).values()))
     for lst in df["data"]], columns=["content", "count"]
)

out = df.join(counts)
```

Output :

```
print(counts)

                                                         content  count
0  media-type-removed,request-parameter-removed,api-path-removed  1,1,1
```

Input used (`df`):

|  | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'id': 'request-parameter-removed', 'level': 1, 'operation': 'GET', 'path': '/textile/simulator'}, {'id': 'api-path-removed', 'level': 1, 'operation': 'GET', 'path': '/textile/simulator/detailed'}, {'id': 'media-type-removed', 'level': 1, 'operation': 'GET', 'path': '/textile/simulator/{impact}'}] |

***Update :***

Based on the updated question/input, assuming that the rows in the column `content` and holding lists of dictionnaries may contain at least one or more `id`*s*, you can use :

```
def process(row):
    if isinstance(row, list) and len(row) > 0:
        content = ",".join(set(d["id"] for d in row))
        count = ",".join(str(c) for c in Counter(d["id"] for d in row).values())
        return content, count

counts = pd.DataFrame(
    [process(r) for r in df["content"]], columns=["new_content", "count"]
)

out1 = counts.dropna().agg(",".join).to_frame().T
```

Output :

```
print(out1)
                                               new_content count
0  new-required-request-property,request-parameter-removed   1,2
```

If you want to join it back the processed counts to `df`, use `out2 = df.join(counts)` :

Output (`out2`) :

|  | content | new_content | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'id': 'new-required-request-property', 'text': "added the new required request property 'todaySubsectionList'", 'level': 0, 'operation': 'PUT', 'path': '/frequent'}] | new-required-request-property | 1 |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Backward compatibility errors (1): |  |  |
|  | error at original_source=/Users/, in API GET /api/v2/templates api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. |  |  |
| 3 | [{'id': 'request-parameter-removed', 'text': "deleted the 'header' request parameter 'Accept'", 'level': 1, 'operation': 'GET', 'path': '/reviews'}, {'id': 'request-parameter-removed', 'text': "deleted the 'header' request parameter 'Content-Type'", 'level': 1, 'operation': 'GET', 'path': '/reviews'}] | request-parameter-removed | 2 |
| 4 | [] |  |  |
| 5 | [] |  |  |
| 6 | [] |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

[`.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html) could help.

```
df_long = df.explode("content")

(pd.json_normalize(df_long["content"])
   .set_index(df_long.index)
   .groupby(by="id", level=0)["id"]
   .value_counts()
)
```

```
   id                           
0  new-required-request-property    1
3  request-parameter-removed        2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```